# Grouping records by using aggregate function Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a Table in Oracle as below

```
   CREATE TABLE Employees(EmpId INT, 
                          EmpName VARCHAR2(30), 
                          Designation VARCHAR2(30), 
                          Salary INT);
```

I have inserted rows in table as below

```
INSERT ALL 
   INTO Employees(EmpId, EmpName, Designation, Salary)VALUES(101, 'Scott', 'Clerk', 2500)
   INTO Employees(EmpId, EmpName, Designation, Salary)VALUES(102, 'Mac', 'Manager', 5000)
   INTO Employees(EmpId, EmpName, Designation, Salary)VALUES(103, 'Steave', 'Clerk', 1500)
   INTO Employees(EmpId, EmpName, Designation, Salary)VALUES(104, 'John', 'Clerk', 1500)
   INTO Employees(EmpId, EmpName, Designation, Salary)VALUES(105, 'Jack', 'Analyst', 2500)
   INTO Employees(EmpId, EmpName, Designation, Salary)VALUES(106, 'Paul', 'Manager', 4500)
   INTO Employees(EmpId, EmpName, Designation, Salary)VALUES(107, 'Ryan', 'Clerk', 1250)
   INTO Employees(EmpId, EmpName, Designation, Salary)VALUES(108, 'Phillipe', 'Analyst', 3150)
   INTO Employees(EmpId, EmpName, Designation, Salary)VALUES(109, 'Clark', 'Clerk', 1200)
   INTO Employees(EmpId, EmpName, Designation, Salary)VALUES(110, 'Arnold', 'Clerk', 1100)
   SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Below is the Short overview of Table

[image]

Now I want to get the Top paid people grouped by designation as Below

```
EmpName   Designation  Salary
Phillipe  Analyst      3150 
Scott     Clerk        2500
Mac       Manager      5000
```

I want empName, Designation and max Salary by designation.

I Tried the below query but it is bringing all records

```
SELECT EmpName, Designation, max(Salary) AS msal
  FROM Employees
 GROUP BY Designation, EmpName 
 ORDER BY Designation, msal DESC
```

Thanks for Reply

Comment: Your EMPLOYEES table doesn't have a Department.  So do you mean  empName, Designation and max Salary by *designation* ?  Either way, please correct your question.

Comment: Thanks you i have done the Edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean 'designation' rather than 'department', you can do this with an analytic query:

```
SELECT EmpName, Designation, Salary
FROM (
    SELECT EmpName, Designation, Salary,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Designation ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS rn
      FROM Employees
)
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Designation;

EMPNAME                        DESIGNATION                        SALARY
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------
Phillipe                       Analyst                              3150 
Scott                          Clerk                                2500 
Mac                            Manager                              5000
```

The inner query applies a ranking to each row, with 1 representing the highest salary in each designation (and allows ties). The outer query then restircts the resulsts to only show the highest-ranking row(s) for each designtation.

In your original verion you're `group by` isn't really doing anything because it includes effectivley all columns - except empid, but that doesn't make a difference unless you have two people with the same name. You'd need to find the max for the designation, and then find the records which matched that max value, which would mean looking at the same table; for example:

```
SELECT EmpName, Designation, Salary
  FROM Employees
 WHERE (Designation, Salary) IN (
     SELECT Designation, MAX(Salary)
       FROM Employees
      GROUP BY Designation
  )
ORDER BY Designation;
```

... or peterm's correlated subquery; but I prefer the analytic route, particularly for larger tables, because you only hit the table once. And I find it clearer, personally.

Answer (score 3):

A version with a correlated subquery

```
SELECT EmpName, Designation, Salary
  FROM Employees e
 WHERE Salary = (SELECT MAX(Salary) 
                   FROM Employees 
                  WHERE Designation = e.Designation)
```

or with a `JOIN`

```
SELECT e.EmpName, e.Designation, e.Salary
  FROM Employees e JOIN 
(
  SELECT Designation, MAX(Salary) Salary
    FROM Employees 
   GROUP BY Designation
) q ON e.Designation = q.Designation
   AND e.Salary = q.Salary
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/feee6/3)** demo for both queries

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  max(EmpName) keep (dense_rank last order by salary) AS EmpName
, Designation
, max(Salary) keep (dense_rank last order by salary)  AS Salary
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Designation
;
```